# Building LablGtk fails

Tags: gtk, ocaml, configure

I'm trying to build `LablGtk` to enable building `CoqIDE` from source.
I used `lablgtk-2.18.7.tar.gz` from [here](http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/). When I tried to `configure-make` it I got this error (and similar other errors):

```
File "gdk.ml", line 346, characters 2-55:
346 |   external create : len:int -> t = "ml_point_array_new"
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error (warning 61): This primitive declaration uses type t, which is unannotated and
unboxable. The representation of such types may change in future
versions. You should annotate the declaration of t with [@@boxed]
or [@@unboxed].
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lablgtk's Makefile is turning all warnings into errors, which tends to break with new compiler versions. You can fix this behavior by removing `-warn-error A-52` from the Makefile.