# Build Coq and CoqIDE from source

Tags: coq, configure

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195044/building-lablgtk-fails) I managed to install `LablGtk` (I think) but still when I try to `configure-make` `Coq` I get the following message that `CoqIDE` will not be built:

```
$ ./configure
You have OCaml 4.09.0+dev0-2019-01-18. Good!
You have OCamlfind 1.7.1. Good!
You have native-code compilation. Good!
You have the Num library installed. Good!
Warning: Incomplete LablGtk2 (via ocamlfind): no /usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.04.0/lablgtk2/gSourceView2.cmi.
Warning: Incomplete LablGtk2 (in OCaml library): no /usr/lib/ocaml/lablgtk2/gSourceView2.cmi.
LablGtk2 not found:
=> no CoqIde will be built.
Where should I install the Coq binaries [/usr/local/bin]?
```

How can I make sure `LablGtk` is installed? or if something else is missing?

EDIT:

I ran `sudo make install` again from the extracted `LablGtk` folder and I now see it failed because it already has this library, but it is somehow associated with an **old** ocaml version (???):

```
$ sudo make install
ocamlfind: Package lablgtk2 is already installed
 - (file /usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.04.0/lablgtk2/META already exists)
Makefile:400: recipe for target 'findlib-install' failed
make[1]: *** [findlib-install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/oren/Downloads/lablgtk-2.18.7/src'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: I would move the directory `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.04.0/` to a safe location, e.g. `/tmp` and try building lablgtk2 again making sure it is built with OCaml 4.09.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov that did not work, it still complained: `ocamlfind: Conflict with another package: Library dlllablgnomeui.so is already installed`

Comment: What is the location of the existing `dlllablgnomeui.so`?

Comment: You seem to mix two installations of OCaml. How did you install OCaml 4.09 ?

Comment: @eponier you're right, I can't get rid of the old one. I built the new one from source.

Comment: The old one may have been installed using the package manager, so you could try to remove all OCaml packages of your distribution, but that's a bit radical. One solution that is quite flexible is using [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/) to manage multiple OCaml installations (so-called "switches"). opam takes care of your environment so that only one OCaml installation is detected at the same time.